# Find source file that contains the current code

Tags: java, file-io

I'm trying to write Java code to find the source code file in a directory. I will compile the file and then place it in some other directory and the program has to find the file, now I think I am doing right but it is still  giving `File not Found` every time I run it.

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class myframe extends JFrame{

    public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException
    {
        myframe g=new myframe();

        MyPanel mp=new MyPanel();
        g.add(mp);
        mp.setSize(1000,1000);
        g.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        g.setSize(500,500);
        g.setVisible(true);
        g.setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    }
}

class MyPanel extends JPanel
{
    File ff,ff2;
    JTextArea ta;
    JTextField jt;
    JScrollPane jsp;
    String[] names;
    File ff3;
    FileInputStream fis;
    String t;
    String s;
    static int flag=0;


    MyPanel() throws IOException
    {
        myframe mf= new myframe();
        setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        ta= new JTextArea();
        jt=new JTextField();
        add(ta,"Center");
        add(jt,"North");
        jsp= new JScrollPane(ta);
        add(jsp);

        File r =new File("C:/");
        t=mf.getClass().getName();
        String g=".java";
        String s= t+g;
        System.out.println(""+s);
        File[] array=r.listFiles();
        System.out.println("hey");
        if(array !=null){
            //RecursiveFileList rfl = new RecursiveFileList();
            fileList((r));
            System.out.println("hey");
        }
        else
            jt.setText("Directory is empty");


    }

    public void fileList( File dir) throws IOException,NullPointerException{

        // fnames = dir.listFiles();


        // for(int i=0; i<fnames.length; i++){


        // fnames[i].listFiles();


        if(dir.isFile()){
            //System.out.println("hey");
            if((dir.getName()).equals(s)){

                flag=1;
                System.out.println("hey");
                jt.setText(""+dir.getAbsolutePath());
                fis= new FileInputStream(dir);
                byte[] b= new byte[(int)dir.length()];
                fis.read(b);
                for(int j=0;j<b.length;j++)
                {
                    ta.append(""+(char)b[j]);
                }

                return;

            }

        }
        else if (dir.isDirectory()){

            File[] fnames=dir.listFiles();

            if (fnames !=null){
                for(File f4:fnames){


                    if(f4!=null){
                        fileList(f4);

                        if(flag==1){
                            System.out.println("hey");
                            return;
                        }
                    }
                    else
                        jt.setText("Get LOST");
                }
            }
            /*jt.setText(""+fnames[i].getAbsolutePath());
            fis= new FileInputStream(fnames[i]);
            byte[] b= new byte[(int)fnames[i].length()];
            fis.read(b);
            for(int j=0;j<b.length;j++)
            {
            ta.append(""+(char)b[j]);
            }*/
        }
        else if(flag==0)
        jt.setText("file not found");

    }
}
```

Comment: Is this just for practice? Most editors/IDEs have "Find in files". Eclipse has CTRL+H (I remove all search menus but File search), Notepad++ has CTRL+SHIFT+F, just about every editor with syntax highlighting has this feature. I mean if this is just for practice, that's cool. But if this is for functionality, you probably have it already.

Comment: what is System.out.println(""+s); printing

Comment: system.out.println is printing the name of file(thats just for my convinence to just check if the file name is correct or not)

Comment: corsiKa i am not finding anything in Files i am trying to find the file.

Comment: You have used the variable `s` in the line `if((dir.getName()).equals(s)){` , but where is it initialized? Try initializing it with the filename.

Answer (score 1):

Your code is not clear enough, but it seems that you just passing a file object with path 'c:/'. This is not a file at all.

Actually this kind of problem is easy to debug. Try to use debug perspective in eclipse, monitor the respective variables to see why the code goes into the code you are not intended to.